# Peewee Select * and additional fields

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I would like to do something like:

`select *, concat(firstname, lastname) from user;`

I understand you can do the following for select *:

`User.select()`

Is it possible to do something like:

`User.select(User.*, fn.Concat(User.firstname, User.lastname))`

Is there a way to do this without explicitly selecting all the columns individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
User.select(User, fn.CONCAT(User.firstname, User.lastname).alias('fullname'))
```

(I'm using the model class to indicate I want all the fields from that model)

Comment: of course! Thanks for your answer. Worked as expected.